# Should these Bitcoin Core build warnings be addressed or are they entirely harmless?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, compiling

When I build Bitcoin Core on MacOS I get a number of "overriding a member function" Boost warnings:

e.g.

```
/usr/local/include/boost/signals2/connection.hpp:212:34: warning: 'release_slot' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override' [-Wsuggest-override]
```

Should these be addressed in future or are they entirely harmless and safe to ignore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this particular warning can be ignored. The given file name is of a system dependency and so there is nothing that can be done about it except to wait for the boost project to fix the error and publish a fix that you can apply to your system.

You can suppress these warnings by configuring with `--enable-suppress-external-warnings`.

Comment: This should be on the build documentation, so many warnings obscure the build process